# Improving repeated production and merging of tabyls

Tags: r, dplyr

Please help me improve my code. The code below does exactly what I want - produce a table with frequencies and percentages. However, I have no doubt the first half could be made more efficient. NB.The All group is more than just the four states that I am showing separately.

```
All.Q1<-data2 %>% tabyl(`Q1 - Position`, show_na=F) %>%  adorn_pct_formatting()
NSW.Q1<-data2 %>% filter(State=="NSW") %>% tabyl(`Q1 - Position`, show_na=F) %>%  adorn_pct_formatting()
QLD.Q1<-data2 %>% filter(State=="QLD") %>% tabyl(`Q1 - Position`, show_na=F) %>%  adorn_pct_formatting()
VIC.Q1<-data2 %>% filter(State=="VIC") %>% tabyl(`Q1 - Position`, show_na=F) %>%  adorn_pct_formatting()
WA.Q1<-data2 %>% filter(State=="WA") %>% tabyl(`Q1 - Position`, show_na=F) %>%  adorn_pct_formatting()

tab.Q1<-Reduce(function(...) merge(..., all = TRUE, by = "Q1 - Position"),
       list(All.Q1, NSW.Q1, QLD.Q1, VIC.Q1, WA.Q1))

tab.Q1 %>% kable(digits=2, col.names = c("Position", col.au)) %>% kable_styling(bootstrap_options = c("striped", "hover"))
```

Comment: Can you add data using `dput(data2)` ? Also include all the non-base packages that you are using.

Answer (score 1):

Hard to tell whether this is correct without underlying data, give it a go, and if its not what you need call `dput(data2)` and c+p the result from the console into your question as @Ronak Shah suggests, this is SO standard practice ! Good luck, and I hope this solution is what you are after:

```
data2 %>% 
mutate(State = as.character("All Australia")) %>% 
bind_rows(., data2 %>% mutate(State = as.character(State))) %>% 
group_by(State) %>% 
tabyl(`Q1 - Position`, show_na = FALSE) %>% 
adorn_pct_formatting() %>% 
ungroup() %>% 
kable(digits = 2, col.names = c("Position", col.au)) %>% 
kable_styling(bootstrap_options = c("striped", "hover"))
```

Comment: @Lyndon Walker please upvote and accept my answer if you have found it to be useful.